# laravel: php artisan optimize command return 'not serializable' error

Tags: php, laravel

laravel 6

when I run: `php artisan optimize`

I got this error:

> Your configuration files are not serializable.

I checked and I found the target file:

error in: **config\sluggable.php** beacuse of this part of code:

```
 'method' => function($string, $separator = '-') {
      $_transliteration = ["/ö|œ/" => "e",
          "/ü/" => "e",
          "/Ä/" => "e",
          "/Ü/" => "e",
          "/Œ/" => "E",
          "/ƒ/" => ""];
      $quotedReplacement = preg_quote($separator, '/');
      $merge = [
          '/[^\s\p{Zs}\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lo}\p{Lt}\p{Lu}\p{Nd}]/mu' => ' ',
          '/[\s\p{Zs}]+/mu' => $separator,
          sprintf('/^[%s]+|[%s]+$/', $quotedReplacement, $quotedReplacement) => '',
      ];
      $map = $_transliteration + $merge;
      unset($_transliteration);
      return preg_replace(array_keys($map), array_values($map), $string);
  },
```

I know Closure serialization is not allowed in Laravel. But how can I  rewrite this piece of code using traditional functions in sluggable.php?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Laravel limitation, its a Php one.  There *is* a workaround, but it kind of depends on whether the functionality using that 'method' value is checking for a type-hint of `Closure` or if the content merely needs to be `callable`.

Create a new Class, and apply the Magic `__invoke()` method to it.  Inside that method, execute that Closure and return the result. And set your config to reference an instance of that class. The trick here is the serialization can reference an object instead of a function now, and so long as that function is not applied to a property within that class, it should work, because serialization doesn't collapse methods. The `__invoke()` method then allows whatever downstream behavior to communicate with the object as if it's a function.

I'd advise though, attempting to find a different avenue that doesn't require a Closure at all. If the option exists, it would be cleaner.