# laravel config sluggable: php artisan optimize command return 'not serializable'

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `Closure` function in my sluggble.php configurtion in laravel (7).

**config\sluggable.php** (cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable package)

```
 'method' => function($string, $separator = '-') {
      $_transliteration = ["/ö|œ/" => "e",
          "/ü/" => "e",
          "/Ä/" => "e",
          "/Ü/" => "e",
          "/Œ/" => "E",
          "/ƒ/" => ""];
      $quotedReplacement = preg_quote($separator, '/');
      $merge = [
          '/[^\s\p{Zs}\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lo}\p{Lt}\p{Lu}\p{Nd}]/mu' => ' ',
          '/[\s\p{Zs}]+/mu' => $separator,
          sprintf('/^[%s]+|[%s]+$/', $quotedReplacement, $quotedReplacement) => '',
      ];
      $map = $_transliteration + $merge;
      unset($_transliteration);
      return preg_replace(array_keys($map), array_values($map), $string);
  },
```

**It works in my project** but I get `php artisan optimize command return 'not serializable'` error when I want to cashed it.

I try to define a `__invoke()` method to solve the error.

I try this:

```
 'method' => (new class {
           public function __invoke($string = '', $separator = '-')
           {
               $_transliteration = ["/ö|œ/" => "e",
               "/ü/" => "e",
               ...
               return preg_replace(array_keys($map), array_values($map), $string);
           }
         })(),
```

with this code, the error gone but **the method dosen't work in my project**.

what is my wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60442091/laravel-php-artisan-optimize-command-return-not-serializable-error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel: php artisan optimize command return 'not serializable' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60442091/laravel-php-artisan-optimize-command-return-not-serializable-error)